# Infinite loop in rock,paper,scissors game

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C#. I was making a simple rock, paper, and scissors game. Every time I run the code I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Here's the problematic code:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

Random random = new Random();

bool playagain = true;
String player = "";
int computer = random.Next(1,4);

Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");

player = Console.ReadLine();
player.ToUpper();

while (playagain)
{
    while (player != "ROCK" && player != "PAPER" && player != "SCISSORS")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");
        player = Console.ReadLine();
        player.ToUpper();
    }

    switch (computer) {
        case 1:// computer = rock
            if (player.Equals("ROCK"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : Rock");
                Console.WriteLine("It's a tie !");
            }
            else if (player.Equals("PAPER"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : ROCK");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose !");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("You win !");
            }
            break;
        case 2:// computer = paper
            if (player.Equals("ROCK"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : PAPER");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose !");
            }
            else if (player.Equals("PAPER"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : PAPER");
                Console.WriteLine("It's  a tie  !");
            }
            else// player = scissors 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : PAPER");
                Console.WriteLine("You win !");
            }

            break;
        case 3: // computer = scissors 
            if (player.Equals("ROCK"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("You win !");
            }
            else if (player.Equals("PAPER"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose  !");
            }
            else // player = scissors 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("It's a tie  !");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Every time I run this code, I get stuck in an infinite loop with the console displaying `Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS :`.

Could someone explain to me what is wrong with my code above?

i tried putting the : Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : text outside of the main while loop, but nothing changed, it's very strange.

Comment: When you loose (or win) set playagain = false to you exit the while loop.

Comment: What did you enter as 'player' value?

Comment: In the game of rock, paper, scissors, bug the winner is always bug. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are never modifying the `playagain` variable. You must ask the player for input on whether they want to play again or not. If the input is "no", then set the `playagain` variable to false.

You can add this after the switch case:

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
string response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
playagain = response == "yes";
```

Comment: I added it right after the switch, and i made some tweaks with the code, now the console asks me to pick rock, paper, or scissors but when i pick one i get stuck in a loop where the console displays what the computer picked and who won.....

Comment: Since you mentioned that you made *tweaks* to the code, please ensure that you haven't changed any other parameters in the `random.Next()` function or accidentally removed the `break` keyword.

Comment: Additionally, please note that `player.ToUpper()` won't work as expected in the condition. You should either assign the result to the `player` variable or modify the code to use `Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()`. This ensures that the input is correctly converted to uppercase for the comparison in the condition.

Comment: I know about the uppercase and I fixed it already, that was one of the *tweaks*, and no I didn't change the parameters in random.Next(), still a strange encounter, as the code seems.

Comment: @Indective, you also have to clear player after the switch, eg. player = "";

Answer (score 3):

`player.ToUpper();` does not modify the string, it returns a new string, so it must be `player = player.ToUpper();`